# confused on how to access nested values in json code?

Tags: python, tumblr, pytumblr

using the pytumblr client i get this type of output

```
{
"total_blogs": 2,
"blogs": [
  {
    "name": "testblog",
    "title": "testblog",
    "description": "A testblog",
    "url": "https://testblog.tumblr.com/",
    "uuid": "t:g8wqt6wBUe3AJkJXYHn1",
    "updated": 1526680515 
  },
  {
    "name": "testblog1",
    "title": "testblog1",
    "description": "A testblog1",
    "url": "https://testblog1.tumblr.com/",
    "uuid": "t:qwuedBBFIPMTViKhjozp",
    "updated": 1510382395 
  }],
"_links": {
  "next": {
    "href": "/v2/user/following?offset=20",
    "method": "GET",
    "query_params": {
      "offset": "20"
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

i can print the values of total_blogs and blogs just fine, but I'm having trouble accessing the itnernal values, specifically the url and I haven't been able to apply the tutorials or some of the other examples i've seen here in a way that would help with this issue.

The end game is basically just to be able to loop the program until i obtain all of the url values. I can only access of 20 blogs at a time so that's how many url values i will have to get

[Accessing json array in python without referring to its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048269/accessing-json-array-in-python-without-referring-to-its-name)

an answer in this page seemed to be the solution but attempting to apply it to my code

```
for anything in usrFollowing:
  if isinstance(usrFollowing[anything], list):
    for values in usrFollowing[anything]:
      print(values['blogs']['name'])
```

just gives me KeyError: 'blogs' from the last line. i'm not sure what else i can do at this point

an additional problem i have is figuring out how to output the code into a more readable format. on the tumblr website console, it outputs like the initial code i've shown above, but all I get is just an ongoing line printing to the console. is there any way to change  this?

Comment: `values['blogs']` is a list, so you need to iterate through it or specify and integer index, e.g. `values['blogs'][0]['name']`. It would help if show what you are assigning `usrFollowing` to.

Comment: `print(x['blogs'][0]['name'])` - https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/R7D

Comment: `client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient()`
`userFollowing = client.Following()`

is this what you are referring to @NikolajBaer

Comment: I see now, I was looking on the JSON side but not the python part of it.

Comment: If you can deserialize from JSON to Python data structures, then you have Python data, not JSON data -- JSON is no longer an essential part of the question once deserialization succeeds. (That is to say: Your problem would be just as applicable if you were handed a Python data structure as input with the same form, instead of having JSON in the first place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should retrieve the blog urls that your tumblr follows:

```
import pytumblr
client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(...)  # replace ... with your credentials

usrFollowing = client.following()
for blog in usrFollowing['blogs']:
    print(blog['url'])
```

I think the way to understand this structure is one piece at a time.

The `usrFollowing` var is a dictionary

```
...
usrFollowing = client.following()
for key in usrFollowing.keys():
    print(key)

# outputs:
#   blogs
#   _links
#   total_blogs
```

So, to access each blog, we can iterate over them using the key `blogs`:

```
...
usrFollowing = client.following()
for blog in usrFollowing['blogs']:
    print(blog)
# outputs something like:
#   {u'updated': 1539793245, u'uuid': u't:CwoihvyyOxn8Mk5TUS0KDg', u'title': u'Tumblr Engineering', u'url': u'https://engineering.tumblr.com/', u'name': u'engineering', u'description': u'Dispatches from the intrepid tinkerers behind technology at Tumblr.'}
#   {u'updated': 1545058816, u'uuid': u't:0aY0xL2Fi1OFJg4YxpmegQ', u'title': u'Tumblr Staff', u'url': u'https://staff.tumblr.com/', u'name': u'staff', u'description': u''}
```

There are several ways to output objects in a more "human" format, use `pprint` or convert the object to JSON specifying an indentation amount:

```
...

import pprint
import json

print('Python pretty-printed')
for blog in usrFollowing['blogs']:
    pprint.pprint(blog)

print('')

print('JSON pretty-printed')
for blog in usrFollowing['blogs']:
    print(json.dumps(blog, indent=2))
# outputs something like:
#   Python pretty-printed
#   {u'description': u'Dispatches from the intrepid tinkerers behind technology at Tumblr.',
#    u'name': u'engineering',
#    u'title': u'Tumblr Engineering',
#    u'updated': 1539793245,
#    u'url': u'https://engineering.tumblr.com/',
#    u'uuid': u't:CwoihvyyOxn8Mk5TUS0KDg'}
#   {u'description': u'',
#    u'name': u'staff',
#    u'title': u'Tumblr Staff',
#    u'updated': 1545058816,
#    u'url': u'https://staff.tumblr.com/',
#    u'uuid': u't:0aY0xL2Fi1OFJg4YxpmegQ'}
#   
#   JSON pretty-printed
#   {
#     "updated": 1539793245,
#     "uuid": "t:CwoihvyyOxn8Mk5TUS0KDg",
#     "title": "Tumblr Engineering",
#     "url": "https://engineering.tumblr.com/",
#     "name": "engineering",
#     "description": "Dispatches from the intrepid tinkerers behind technology at Tumblr."
#   }
#   {
#     "updated": 1545058816,
#     "uuid": "t:0aY0xL2Fi1OFJg4YxpmegQ",
#     "title": "Tumblr Staff",
#     "url": "https://staff.tumblr.com/",
#     "name": "staff",
#     "description": ""
#   }
```

These dictionaries have a `url` key, so you can print them with:

```
...
usrFollowing = client.following()
for blog in usrFollowing['blogs']:
    print(blog['url'])
# outputs something like:
#   https://engineering.tumblr.com/
#   https://staff.tumblr.com/
```